# need reloadData on table after every performFetch?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This my be silly question. Bu do I have to call

```
[table reloadData];
```

after every time when I call performFetch on NSFetchedResultsController to update table view?

```
[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:nil];
```

Comment: I have the same thought for a while:) Hope someone can give a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting your UITableViewController as the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, you can implement the `controllerDidChangeContent:` method:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Take a look at [this answer here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840778/refresh-nsfetchedresultscontroller-data).

Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Happy coding :)

Comment: But if the data already exists in coreData and you call `performFetch` then `controllerDidChangeContent` isn't called.

Answer (score 3):

if the method `[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:nil];` results into new dataset, and you want to load your table with that new data, you will have to do the job.